# Programmatically change field heading type in qgis2web plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis2web

I have a dozen layers each with more than a dozen fields. When I run the qgis2web plugin, there are 3 options on how each field can be displayed (`no label`, `inline label`, and `header label`).

I do not want to manually go through over a hundred fields and setting their field style.

Is there a way, once the map is exported using **Leaflet**, to change the field display using some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the plugin code **before** you export your map.

> .........For your own purpose: take a look at line 808-810 of the file maindialog.py:

self.attrWidget.addItem("no label")
self.attrWidget.addItem("inline label")
self.attrWidget.addItem("header label")

If you switch order to:

```
            self.attrWidget.addItem("inline label")
            self.attrWidget.addItem("header label")
            self.attrWidget.addItem("no label")..................
```

source: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/833

I have not tested the solution for the current version, so I hope, it could also help you now. You know it: You must repeat the code change with a new qgis2web version.